# In Typeahead search. Need ID of the Item. After selecting the Item from search box not able to get item ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead

Need ID of the Item.
After selecting the Item from search box not able to get item ID.

[image]

View.php

```
<script src="bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

<input class="typeahead form-control" id="search_it" spellcheck="false" type="text">

<h3>view.js<h3>

<script>
  $('#search_it').typeahead({
            items: 10,
            source: function (query, result) {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "dropdown/ajaxpro",
                        data: 'query=' + query,            
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (data) {
                            result($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item.text;
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
            updater: function (item) { 
              return item; 
            }, 
            afterSelect: function (item) { 
              alert(item.id);
            }

        });
</script>
```

JSON Response

```
0: Object { id: "1", text: "Lee Jeans" }
1: Object { id: "2", text: "Raymand Shirt" }​
2: Object { id: "3", text: "Cotton King T-shirt" }​
3: Object { id: "4", text: "Sieram Blazers" }​
4: Object { id: "6", text: "Kolkatta Sherwani Dress" }​
5: Object { id: "7", text: "Men Indian Kurta" }​
6: Object { id: "8", text: "Tourist Bag" }​
7: Object { id: "9", text: "Lee Jackets" }​
8: Object { id: "10", text: "Men Caps" }​
```

length: 9

Comment: what error do you encounter ? never debug with alert() use console.log

Comment: Hello sir, i am not able to get its ID after selecting item from search box.